# CSS + FONT + Image replacement

Tags: html, css, fonts

I stumbled on a site yesterday and forgot to bookmark the url.  I'm stumped though because google is not helping me trace my steps.  The site was basically a text to image converter for preserving your specific fonts in the browser.  What made this one unique was that the text was fully selectable, however what was being displayed was the image that was generated using the desired font.

They required a subscription to their service so I disregarded it and moved on.  Turns out I left too quickly and I'm interested in trying the product now.  Does anyone know what website I stumbled upon, and if they have experience with it?

BTW, I'd recognize the link if I saw it.  It was something like freemefont.com or something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a list of commercial webfont service:

- [fontspring](http://www.fontspring.com/)
- [kernest](http://kernest.com/)
- [typekit](http://typekit.com/)
- [typefront](http://typefront.com/)
- [typotheque](http://www.typotheque.com/webfonts)

if it's not one of these you stumbled on you can try the free alternatives (harder to setup) listed in the other answers.

Ill add to the (free) ones already proposed a php based one:

- [PCDTR](http://code.google.com/p/pcdtr/)

Answer (score 1):

You may mean cufón:  [Take a look here](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/).  It's at least something like you describe, you upload fonts, and it generates javascript to render the same or as close as possible I guess, as those fonts would.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  This was not the one I saw yesterday but I will take a look.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [TypeKit](http://typekit.com/) for that - they don't really create images, but rather supply a font via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Facelift? http://facelift.mawhorter.net/

Another alternative, which I'm pretty sure you don't mean, is sIFR: http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/

Answer (score 0):

these links should help you out

[link1](http://www.dezinerfolio.com/2009/03/31/dynamic-font-replacement-solutions)

[link2](http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/11/selectable-font-image-replacement.html)